# Are Volume IDs same to a device across various machines?

Tags: usb, partitioning

If you have a usb with multiple partitions. Say one of them is hidden. And you make a batch file to open that partition via Volume ID (`start \\?\Volume{abc0000-0000-0000-0000-00a000000000}\`).
Would that file work on other machines as well? Or that Volume IDs are native to that machine and every PC has its own volume IDs for partitions on that USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume ID on the USB disk is contained inside the partition table
that is found on the disk itself.

The ID wouldn't change because you connected the disk on another computer.